# How to realize the character group as a Lie/algebraic/topological group?

Tags: lie-groups, topological-groups, algebraic-groups, characters, finitely-generated

Let $G$ be an abelian group. The [character group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_group) of $G$ is the group of all homomorphisms from $G$ to $\mathbb{C}^\times$ under pointwise multiplication, denoted $\widehat{G}$. I am mainly interested in the case $G$ is a finitely generated abelian group. As groups, $\widehat{G}$ is isomorphic to $F \times (\Bbb C^\times)^{r}$ with $F$ is a finite abelian group and $r=\mathrm{rank}(G)$. 
The latter group is a (compact abelian) [Lie group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group)/direct product of a finite group with an (abelian connected complex linear) [algebraic group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_group)/[topological group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_group).

Is it enough to say that $\widehat{G}$ has all the properties that a  Lie/algebraic/topological group has?
To put it another way, how much of extra algebra/topology can we earn from the group isomorphism $\widehat{G}\cong F \times (\Bbb C^\times)^{r}$? For example, the cardinality of $F$ enumerates the number of connected components of $F \times (\Bbb C^\times)^{r}$. Does this make sense if we speak of "connected components" of $\widehat{G}$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin_duality

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb{C}^{\times}$ is a Lie group and the character group inherits its Lie group structure (in the finitely generated case). This is because every f.g. abelian group is a quotient of a f.g. free abelian group and so every character group of such a group is obtained from the character group of $\mathbb{Z}^n$, which is $(\mathbb{C}^{\times})^n$ (with its usual Lie group structure), by considering the subgroup respecting some relations (which inherits a Lie group structure).

Said another way, taking the character group defines a contravariant functor from f.g. abelian groups to Lie groups. If you replace $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$ with $S^1$ you get a nicer functor which is a special case of Pontryagin duality, and which among other things is fully faithful.

Comment: Can I say that $\widehat{G}$ has a structure of a Lie group? The isomorphism mentioned above is just for groups, and probably the isomorphism between Lie groups needs more than that.

Comment: @user: you can transport the Lie group structure across the isomorphism. There's an additional argument you need to make to show why this Lie group structure doesn't depend on a choice of presentation, but it's not hard.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on it? Maybe it relies on the fact that we have the group isomorphism not just bijection of sets.